# get progid of a running process

Tags: c#, progid

Is it possible to get the progID of a running process? Using C#?

Answer (score 2):

[User `Process` class members.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process_members.aspx)

These functions will help-

`GetProcesses`
`GetProcessesByName`

To get current process, use-

`GetCurrentProcess`

Answer (score 0):

What is `progID`? Seems that you need [`System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.id.aspx).

Comment: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/-progid--key